# How does Facebook keep a TCP connection open in Android even when the device is asleep?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, cordova, socket.io

I'm trying to create a chat application with Cordova on the frontend, Socket.IO Node.JS server on the backend. However, the connection with the server dies a few seconds after the phone falls asleep. How do chat applications like Facebook or Whatsapp solve this problem and push notifications to the user? Is it possible to implement this in cordova without writing native code? I would like to support both Android and iOS with my application. Thanks!

Comment: you shouldnt need you own tcp connection active if you are using push notifications, the push notification can give a snippet of the text, then when you go into the app it actually downloads the messages

Comment: ok, I admit I used the term "push notification" lightly, I don't know the definition. What I meant was, how does Facebook notify users (by vibration, sound alert) that there's a new message, even if the device is sleeping?

Comment: heh well, my statement still stands, look into how push notifications work, this is exactly what its for :P apple and google handle this stuff quite well, dont need to muck around with your own network connections

Comment: hm... I think that in my case, I really do need my own network connections, because I'm not dealing with registered users at all, just anonymous users, and the only way to distinguish between online and offline users is whether or not they have a network connection open

Comment: hmm well its not really possible to keep a network connection open indefinitely in the background, iOS has quite a strict policy on apps doing work while in the background.

Comment: You can use a Service to manage a background task using the same application process that calls it. This service is always available in the background (startService()) until it is being asked to stop (stopService()) even when the application process has been paused. Facebook has a running service called MessagingService to complement its main Facebook process. I use a Service to always listen to traffic on TCP/IP stack. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: I see, I guess there's no way to make a service work cross-platform with cordova though, right? I will need a separate implementation for each platform (Android, iOS)?